# mpandroidchart differnt label color for y-axis

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I am using the library `com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.0.9` for displaying a barchart .

I want to set different colors for each label in the Y axis. Is it possible to do this?  How do I do this?